# creating and removing symlinks

Tags: rust, filesystems, symlink

Hi im trying to symlink a directory in rust and later tried unlinking it. Im looking for a cross-platform method to do this.

Ive tried using the [symlink](https://crates.io/crates/symlink) crate to do this. In unix systems, the crate uses [`fs::remove_file`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_file.html) for removing symlinks. But this throws an error when actually using it. The error returns `path is a Directory`. I also saw the same function being used in fnm ([here](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm/blob/master/src/fs.rs)). Idk what im supposed to do.
As for creating symlinks, the crate uses [`std::os::unix::fs::symlink`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/fn.symlink.html) for creating the symlink, but for some reason my symlinked dir remains empty. The overall code used is more or less the following:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

#[cfg(unix)]
pub fn symlink_dir<P: AsRef<Path>, U: AsRef<Path>>(from: P, to: U) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::os::unix::fs::symlink(from, to)?;
    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(windows)]
pub fn symlink_dir<P: AsRef<Path>, U: AsRef<Path>>(from: P, to: U) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    junction::create(from, to)?;
    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(windows)]
pub fn remove_symlink_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::fs::remove_dir(path)?;
    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(unix)]
pub fn remove_symlink_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::fs::remove_file(path)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Still haven't tried it on windows so not sure wether the windows counter part works. Only tried it on a linux os using github codespaces.
Im trying to make a nvm like version manager for Dart ([here](https://github.com/Yakiyo/dsm)) and i need to symlink the currently used version's directory to a `current` dir or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent found an answer to my question but i did end up solving it. Not sure why using `fs::remove_file` wasnt working for me. So i brute forced it and just removed the symlink using `fs::remove_dir_all`. As long as it works, im good with it. I've been using it [here](https://github.com/Yakiyo/dsm/blob/1e81e3db947b7a64b5fcef1d114d9bf39183fb76/src/commands/use.rs#L32), working fine, tho i still do think using `fs::remove_file` on unix and `fs::remove_dir` on windows should be how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Rust documentation for `std::fs::remove_file` says that it corresponds to the `unlink` syscall on Unix, and Unix documentation for unlink states `If the name referred to a symbolic link, the link is removed`. Therefore, it should work to use `std::fs::remove_file` to remove a symlink (and thereby also `symlink::remove_symlink_dir`)

It appears that a trailing slash can cause the error you mentioned. For example, calling unlink on `/path/to/my/symlink` should work, but not on `/path/to/my/symlink/`.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but when i printed the path in stdout, it didnt have any trailing slash. An image [here](https://i.imgur.com/Paa3WwK.png)